# "An error occurred submitting the edit" when trying to post an SQL snippet

Tags: support

When I tried to post this SQL as code, Stack Overflow failed with this error:

> An error occurred submitting the edit

Any idea what the problem is?

> [image: screenshot of the SQL snippet]

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image as a courtesy to those who wants to help you.

Comment: It's my problem that I can not publish this code

Comment: Can you provide any more context? if you've not got enough non-code content and it's a question you won't be able to post it

Comment: I have seen reports where firewalls and/or virusscanners block content that looks like a sql-injection. Try a different device / network.

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser, go to the network tab, submit the question again and look at the request and the response. Those will contain more details about what happened. You can [edit] to include them here.